# Display JavaScript object in a ul list recursively

Tags: javascript, html, recursion

I'm trying to display an JavaScript object in a HTML `ul` list fashion.
The object represents a binary tree and has this format:

```
{
    "val":2,
    "l":{
        "val":1,
        "l":{},
        "r":{}
    },
    "r":{
        "val":4,
        "l":{},
        "r":{
            "val":5,
            "l":{},
            "r":{}
        }
    }
}
```

The result I need to accomplish is this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">4</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">5</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I wrote this code here in order to get the respective string of the result, but it doesn't generate the correct result.

```
function buildList(data){
    var html = '';
    if(data.val){
        if(data.l){
            html += '<ul>';
            html += buildList(data.l);
        }
        html += '<li>';
        html += '<a href="#">' + data.val + '</a>'
        html += '</li>';
        if(data.r){
            html += buildList(data.r);
            html += '</ul>';
        }
    }

    return html;
}
```

Any guesses or clue would be appreciated.

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: The function works fine. Maybe try inserting into the page or using the console to log it's return value?

Comment: What are you doing with that string??

Comment: Hi @JonathanM,
The result i'm getting is this:
**Goal:**

`<ul><li><a href="#">2</a><ul><li><a href="#">1</a></li><li><a href="#">4</a><ul><li><a href="#">5</a></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>`


**Current Result:**
`<ul><ul><li><a href="#">1</a></li></ul><li><a href="#">2</a></li><ul><li><a href="#">4</a></li><ul><li><a href="#">5</a></li></ul></ul></ul>`

@gforce301,
_This is also what the log shows_

Comment: @dobleUber I'll use the list to display a binary tree. I'm building a Binary Search Tree (BST) program to implement AVL. I can already get the object from a BST. Now I'm trying to display such object in a UL list. We could use an iterative way, but I believe recursion would be much easier.

Comment: Here is my try with jquery https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1811/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dynamic recursive approach by building DOM nodes with the wanted object.

```js
function buildDOM(tree) {
    function buildLI(node) {
        var li = document.createElement('li'),
            a = document.createElement('a');

        a.href = '#';
        a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(node.val));
        li.appendChild(a);
        if (('l' in node) && ('val' in node.l) || ('r' in node) && ('val' in node.r)) {
            li.appendChild(buildDOM(node));
        }
        return li;
    }

    var ul = document.createElement('ul');                

    if (('l' in tree) && ('val' in tree.l)) {
        ul.appendChild(buildLI(tree.l));
    }
    if (('r' in tree) && ('val' in tree.r)) {
        ul.appendChild(buildLI(tree.r));
    }
    return ul;
}

var data = { val: 2, l: { val: 1, l: {}, r: {} }, r: { val: 4, l: {}, r: { val: 5, l: {}, r: {} } } };

document.body.appendChild(buildDOM({ r: data }));
```

Answer (score 2):

**Make life easy**

This is a situation where a little bit of data abstraction goes a looooong way. If you attempt to handle all of the variances in your data in a single function, you will be faced with a big spaghetti of single-branch `if`s and other side-effecting code.

Using data abstraction below, I've reduced complex logic and conditionals down to a single `if/else` statement. I'll step through the code bit-by-bit, then I'll put it all together in a runnable demo at the end

---

**wishful thinking**

I don't want to have to think about (eg) whether val is `{}` or whether `l` or `r` have valid value - this is all meaningless to me. What I would love to write is something like this:

```
const makeTree = ({val, l, r}) => {
  if (val === undefined)
    return []
  else
    return [Node('ul', Node('li', Link('#', val)), ...makeTree(l), ...makeTree(r))]
}
```

This assumes we have two constructors `Node` and `Link` at our disposal. But before we dig into those, we see that `makeTree` returns an Array no matter what. So we'll have to come up with a nice user-facing function that builds this into HTML somehow for us. That will be `makeMenu` – all it does it takes the root node out of the Array and calls `.toElem()` on it

```
const makeMenu = data =>
  makeTree(data)[0].toElem()
```

This also helps us know that we need `.toElem` to be available on the two node types `Node` and `Link`. See, it's nice building your program using wishful thinking because each step you want to have tells you the next thing(s) you have to build.

---

**`Node` and `Link` constructors**

Let's bang out `Node` and `Link` now. They're very straightforward. `Node` is just a generic HTML element of a specific `type` that gets children elements applied to it; notice that each child is expected to have a `.toElem` method as well. `Link` just takes an `href` and some `text` and constructs the element with the attributes set accordingly.

```
const Node = (type, ...children) => ({
  toElem: () => {
    const elem = document.createElement(type)
    children.forEach(child => elem.appendChild(child.toElem()))
    return elem
  }
})

const Link = (href, text) => ({
  toElem: () => {
    const elem = document.createElement('a')
    elem.setAttribute('href', href)
    elem.textContent = text
    return elem
  }
})
```

---

**Putting it all together**

```js
const Node = (type, ...children) => ({
  toElem: () => {
    const elem = document.createElement(type)
    children.forEach(child => elem.appendChild(child.toElem()))
    return elem
  }
})

const Link = (href, text) => ({
  toElem: () => {
    const elem = document.createElement('a')
    elem.setAttribute('href', href)
    elem.textContent = text
    return elem
  }
})

const makeTree = ({val, l, r}) => {
  if (val === undefined)
    return []
  else
    return [Node('ul', Node('li', Link('#', val)), ...makeTree(l), ...makeTree(r))]
}

const makeMenu = data =>
  makeTree(data)[0].toElem()

const data = { "val": 2, "l": { "val": 1, "l": {}, "r": {} }, "r": { "val": 4, "l": {}, "r": { "val": 5, "l": {}, "r": {} } } }

document.body.appendChild(makeMenu(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to rearrange the code a little bit.  Here's a working solution:

```js
function buildList(data){
    var html = '';
    if(data.val){
        html += '<ul><li>';
        html += '<a href="#">' + data.val + '</a>'
        html += '</li>';
        if(data.l){
            html += buildList(data.l);
        }
        if(data.r){
            html += buildList(data.r);
            html += '</ul>';
        }
    }

    return html;
}

var resultDiv = document.getElementById('resultDiv');

var testData = 
    {
        "val":2,
        "l":{
            "val":1,
            "l":{},
            "r":{}
        },
        "r":{
            "val":4,
            "l":{},
            "r":{
                "val":5,
                "l":{},
                "r":{}
            }
        }
    };
    
resultDiv.innerHTML = buildList(testData);
```

```html
<p>Actual Result:</p>
<div id="resultDiv">...</div>

<hr>

<p>Desired Result:</p>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">4</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">5</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dom = buildList(yourObject);
final(dom);

function buildList(data){
    if(data.val){       
        var currentTag = document.createElement('li');
        var atag = document.createElement('a');
        atag.setAttribute("href", "#");
        atag.innerText = data.val;
        currentTag.appendChild(atag);
        if(JSON.stringify(data.l) != "{}" || JSON.stringify(data.r) != "{}"){           
            var ulTag = document.createElement('ul');
            if(JSON.stringify(data.l) != "{}"){
                ulTag.appendChild( buildList(data.l));
            }
            if(JSON.stringify(data.r) != "{}"){
                ulTag.appendChild( buildList(data.r));
            }
            currentTag.appendChild(ulTag);
        }
    }

    return currentTag;
}

function final(body) {
   body = document.createElement('ul').appendChild(body);
}
```